# Getting the width of the user's screen

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I realized this is only possible from the client's side, but I still need to use the width on the server side. So, to get the width, I used `screen.width` in javascript. I tried to get it on the server side and display it so I wrote `response.write(<script>return screen.width;</script>);`. Is there a reason screen.width keeps returning `null` in c# even though it returns 1280 in javascript? 
Edit: 
I also tried to pass the value from js to c# using `hiddenfields`, but it keeps sending the value as null even though its 1280 in js.

Comment: Why do you think you need it server-side?

Comment: Do you realize JavaScript runs after the server is done running? Learn the page life cycle!

Comment: Why do you need the width on the server?

Comment: Well I can use the width on the client side to accomplish what I want, but I would still like to resolve this.

Comment: You can't get the screen size on the first page. You'll have to put the value in a hidden field and post it to the server or send it with ajax/json. Why do you need the screen size?

Answer (score 1):

screen.width is not equal to the width of the user's browser. The width property returns the total width of the visitor's **screen**.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant screen.